# Creating a new group of buttons when clicking on a previous button (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and I wish, when clicking on it, to see a new group of buttons which were not there before be displayed. How can I do it with JS or CSS?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/ny20aq1L/. It is a good practice to append child elements with .appendChild method instead of setting html content.

```html
<button id="buttons-adder">Add some buttons</button>

<div id="buttons-container"></div>

<script>
    const buttonsContainer = document.getElementById('buttons-container');
    const buttonsAdder = document.getElementById('buttons-adder');

    buttonAdder.addEventListener('click', () => {
        addButtons(buttonsContainer, 5);
    });

    function addButtons(container, quantity) {
        const buttons = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
        for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            const newButton = document.createElement('button');
    
            // here you can set all attributes that you need
            newButton.setAttribute('id', 'button-' + i);
            newButton.innerHTML = 'Button #' + i;
    
            buttons.appendChild(newButton);
        }
  
        buttonsContainer.appendChild(buttons);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('hideNow').style.display = 'block';">Button 1</button>
  <div id="hideNow" style="display:none">
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is nice when we have only one button .What if I have many buttons and for each one of these I wish to get others ones. And I want to style these new buttons( giving them a name , a CSS style and when clicking on each one of them to get a new set of buttons by which I can do a JS action like changing the background color . With your solution ,5 new buttons are created , what if i want to get more or less buttons ?And the buttons are kept created when clicking many times on the first button when I wish to get them for the first time only .